# replace values in a column based on another column but following the numeric index from the first replacement

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data.frame that looks like the one above. I need to replace the values in the first columns based on the values on second column but the replacement need to continue the numeric value of column 1, and only replacing the values in column 1 when `!ValB==A`

```
>df1
ValA   ValB
   1      A
   1      A  
   2      A
   2      A
   3      A
   3      A
   4      A
   4      A
   1      B
   1      B
   1      B  
   2      B
   2      B
   3      B
   4      B
   4      B
   1      C
   1      C  
   2      C
   2      C
   3      C
   3      C
   4      C
   1      C
```

What I want is replace the values in column1 but using `ValB==B` as the index for replacing the values in `ValA`. The replacement has to continue the values in `ValA`, i.e, when there is a `1` and the `ValB==B` the `ValA` has to be `5`, the `2` has to be `6` and so on. Please here is the desired output, what will make easier to understand what I am doing. I could do a for loop with `if` and `elseif` statement but I am sure that there is a cleaner way,

Desired output

```
>df1
ValA   ValB
   1      A
   1      A  
   2      A
   2      A
   3      A
   3      A
   4      A
   4      A
   5      B
   5      B
   5      B  
   6      B
   6      B
   6      B
   7      B
   7      B
   8      C
   8      C  
   9      C
   9      C
  10      C
  10      C
  11      C
  12      C
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this. It basically runs a cumulative sum over a boolean vector which tells you whether ValA and ValB of one row are equal to the one of the previous row -

```
# do a running sum of the values
df$c = cumsum(
   c(
   # first value of the result is the same value as the first value of A
   df$ValA[1],
   # go through the second to the last value of the vector and compared it to the first to the n - 1th values
   sapply(
      2:nrow(df),
      function(index) {

         # look for change in value of A and B both
         # if changed then return 1, else return 0
         !(
            df$ValA[index] == df$ValA[index - 1] & 
               df$ValB[index] == df$ValB[index - 1]
         )

      }
   )
))
```

Comment: Unlike the title suggests, it does not seem to be linked to the previous row in the description but more to the "rank" of the level of the second column.

Comment: Thanks @TheComeOnMan, your method works, could you explain a bit?

Comment: I added comments. If you follow them from inside to outwards, you should be able to follow what's happening.